# Determine injective or surjective of these functions

Tags: functions

I have the following functions:

$$
\begin{align}
f&: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \\
g&: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
$$
defined by $f(x, y) = (x + y, x)$ and $g(x, y) = (x - y, y)$.

a) Calculate $g\circ f$ for the originals $(2, 2), (3, 5)$ and $(4, 1)$.
$$
\begin{align}
f(2, 2) &= (2 + 2, 2) = (4, 2) \text{ and then }  g(4, 2) = (4 - 2, 2) = (2, 2)\\
f(3, 5) &= (3 + 5, 3) = (8, 3) \text{ and then } g(8, 3) = (8 - 3, 3) = (5, 3)\\
f(4, 1) &= (4 + 1, 4) = (5, 4) \text{ and then } g(5, 4) = (5 - 4, 4) = (1, 4)
\end{align}
$$

b) Give a function description for the function $h: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with $h = g \circ f$ and show that it counts for all $x$, $y$ element of $\mathbb{N}$.

**I have no idea how to tackle these two questions, don't even know where to begin.**

c) Show that $f$ is injective, but not surjective.

**To show that something is injective, I would need to find an element of the codomain that does not have an element in the domain. To find something that is surjective, I would need to find an element in the codomain that has more than one original.**

**Some sample input/output data:**

input  ->  output
$$
\begin{align}
(0, 0) &\to (0, 0)\\
(0, 1) &\to (1, 0)\\
(0, 2) &\to (2, 0)\\
...&\text{etc...}\\
(1, 0) &\to (1, 1)\\
(1, 1) &\to (2, 1)\\
...&\text{etc...}\\
(2, 0) &\to (2, 2)\\
(2, 1) &\to (3, 2)\\
\end{align}
$$
...etc...

**Now, if I have e.g. the element $(0, 1)$ in the codomain, then there is no corresponding element in the domain. In element $(0, 1), x = 1$, but then $y$ has to be $-1$ to make the $0$, and since the domain is $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, this cannot be.**

**Another example, this time with element $(1, 0)$ in the codomain. This means that $x = 0$, and that $y = 1$. So the corresponding element in the domain should then be $(0, 1)$, but when this element is put into $f$, it goes to $(1, 1)$. In other words, $(1, 0)$ also does not have an original.**

**Is this evidence enough to say that this function is not surjective, or do I still need to prove it further?**

d) We confine the function $f$ now to
$$
f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \{(n, m)\lvert n \geq m\}
$$
still with
$$
f(x, y) = (x + y, x).
$$
Show that the inverse of $f$ now *does* exist, and calculate this inverse.

**My problem here is that there are elements that satisfy $n \geq m$, but these are not inverse. For example, if I put $(2, 1)$ into $f$, the answer is $(3, 2)$. This is not the inverse of $(2, 1)$ What is the thinking mistake I'm making here?**

Comment: You seem to have mixed up your definitions of injective and surjective. You should go take a new look at them.

Comment: But $g$ as defined isn't a function $\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N^2$?

Comment: @Tobias - why? It seems legit :-) Injective is when an element in a domain has a maximum of one element in the codomain (that is none or one). Surjective is when an element from the domain maps to a minimum of one.

Comment: @martini

I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: That is not what you wrote, and this time you mixed up domain and codomain

Comment: I mean the following: $g(2,3) = (-1, 3) \not\in \mathbb N^2$, so $g\colon \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb N$.

Comment: Garth: You might want to learn a bit of LaTeX for future questions.

Comment: *"To show that something is injective, I would need to find an element of the codomain that does not have an element in the domain."*, because, for it to be injective, not every element in the domain maps to an element in the codomain. If this is the case, then there are some elements in the codomain that do not have an element in the domain. I don't see what I say wrong here.

Comment: @Thomas

Where did your answer go to? I had written quite some comment. For example, For (b), I understand till the last part, the (y, x). How does y end up there? if the x part of the function g is x + y, wouldn't that make it x + y - y = x?

Comment: Injective means, in plain English: 2 elements that are not the same element in the domain are, through the mapping function $\phi$, associated with 2 elements in the range (codomain) which are not the same in the codomain. That is obviously not the same as your suggested definition above. Every element maps to the codomain - that's the definition of the codomain. What you write in your comment above is 'not surjective.'

Comment: @GarthMarenghi: It is there again. For the (b) part note that you are evaluating $g$ at $(x+y, x)$ and $g$ is defined by (using different variables) $g(s,t) = (s - t, t)$. Here $s = x+y$ and $t=x$. So $s-t = y$ and $t = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b):

Note that $$h = g\circ f(x,y) = g(x+y, x) = (y, x).$$

For (c):

Surjective? No. For this to be true you would have to be able to find $x,y$ such that $f(x,y) = (x + y, x)= (1,2)$. That would mean $x = 2$ and $y = -1 \notin \mathbb{N}$. So that is not possible.

Injective? Say that $f(x,y) = f(x', y')$. We are assuming that two different inputs give the same output. For $f$ to be injective we need to prove that the inputs actually are the same. So we have $f(x,y) = f(x',y')$ and we need to prove that $x= x'$ adn $y = y'$. That $f(x,y) = f(x', y')$ means that $(x+y, x) = (x' + y', x')$. But if this is true then we certainly have that  $x = x'$. And if $x=x'$ and $x + y = x' + y'$, then it follows that  $y = y'$. Hence $f$ is injective. Note that $x'$ (the backtick or prime or what ever one calls it) is just another element. It isn't doesn't mean that it is necessarily related tot $x$. One could have chosen another variable name instead.

For (d):

Now say that $(n,m)\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq m$. To prove that $f$ now is surjective, you want to find $x,y$ such that $$f(x,y) = (n,m)$$. But since $n\geq m$ you can write $n = m + a$ for $a\geq 0$. So you want $(x,y)$ such that 
$$x + y = n\quad \text{and}\quad x = m.$$ Well pick $x = m$. Then left is to find $y$ such that $x+y = n$, and with the choice of $x$, that means that we want $y$ so that $m + y = n$. That is $m + y = m + a$. This you have if you exactly if pick $y = a$. So $f$ is both injective and surjective here. It is clearly surjective and the injectivity follows from the fat that there was only one way to pick $x$ and $y$.

(I guess that there is the subtle assumption that $0\in \mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions :-)

The other question I wanted to ask you, was what *Say that (x+y,x)=(x′+y′,x′). Then x=x′ and y=y′, so f is injective* means. I have this also in my textbook (f(x) = f(y)) as an explanation of why a something is surjective, but I can't wrap my head around it (also, what do the backticks (x') mean)?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi: First: the $x'$ just means an element in $\mathbb{N}$. One could also have chosen to use another letter instead of $x'$. Second: That $f$ is injective means that **if** $f(x,y) = $f(v,w)$, **then** $x = v$. I can edit my answer to add a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks once again for the additional info. I read your paragraph on injective at For c) a couple of times, but I still don't get it. I mean, if you assume that the inputs are the same (without actually inputting something), then won't they be?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi: Glad to help. Actually I assumed that the **output** was the same and proved that then the **inputs** are the same. This is exactly the definition of what it means to be injective.

Comment: @Tobias I'm sorry to bother you again on this, but there's one thing I thought I grasped, but I'm not sure I do. You say
<br /><br />
*But if this is true then we certainly have that x=x'.*
<br /><br />
Why is it that if we assume that when f(x,y)=f(x',y') means that (x+y,x)=(x'+y',x') is true, that x=x′?

Comment: I'm sorry for the above comment. I meant to write this:

You say

*That $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ means that $(x+y,x)=(x'+y',x')$. But if this is true then we certainly have that $x = x'$.*

Why is it that if we assume that when $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ means that $(x+y,x)=(x'+y',x')$ is true, that $x=x′$?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi" Sorry for the slow response. If $f(x,y) = f(x', y')$ then $(x+y, x) = (x' + y', x')$. The reason for this is the definition of $f(x,y)$. Remember that $f(x,y) = (x+y ,x)$. So we start with $(x+y , x) = f(x,y) = f(x', y') = (x' + y', x')$. Now if $(a,b) = (c,d)$ in general, that means (by definition that $a =b$ and $b = d$. So again, if $(x + y, x) = (x' + y', x')$, then for sure you can conclude that $x = x'$.

Comment: That's okay, you answered! Did you by the way mean with $(a, b) = (c, d)$ that $a$ maps to $c$ instead of $b$? And is it suppose to have equals signs between all of these? $(x+y,x)=f(x,y)=f(x′,y′)=(x′+y′,x′)$? Other than that, I get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @GarthMarenghi: Yes, you are right. I did indeed mean to say that $a = c$ and $b = d$. Yes, there are supposed to be the equal signs. Think about how $f(x,y)$ is defined.

Comment: @Tobias - Right, I got it. For (d), I understand most of the proof, I see what you did and understand that. Though once again, I'm not seeing how $m + y = m + a$ makes this function surjective. Can you please elaborate or give a hint? Thank you.

Comment: @GarthMarenghi: I edited and added more details.

Comment: @Tobias: This is what I get from it: $x$ is easily found because $m$ maps straight to x ($x = m$). And because $m + y = m + a$, it shows that $a$ maps straight to $y$ too, thus $f$ with $n >= m$ is surjective. And, once again, thanks for still helping me out!